# AWS Auto Scaling Group Policy Does Not Trigger

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I've created an autoscaling group, with the scaling-up policy defined as follows - 
CPUUtilization > 70% for more than 300 seconds.

From the instance monitoring metrics, It is evident that it had over 90% cpu usage for over 10 minutes; yet it was not scaled.

Note: I'm using m1.small ec2 instance in the singapore AWS region.

Comment: Is the Alarm triggered in CloudWatch? What does your scaling history show?

Comment: This doesn't have enough information to reliably troubleshoot; can you edit your question to include the definition of your scaling policy, and the definition of your alarm (including which cloudwatch metric it uses and verifying that metric is for instances in your autoscaling group)?